# How to print the output in text file from the list in python?

Tags: python

i searched the stackoverflow and found how to get the files names from a folder.
Now i want to print the results in the file in txt format or xlxs format.
Can you please help me.
I am very newbie to python.
my code is below

```
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join
    from typing import List

   onlyfiles: List[str] = [f for f in listdir('D:\\Options') if isfile(join('D:\\Options',f ))]
   print(onlyfiles)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: hey Vivek, do you get an error runing this code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current code works in the way you want it to. To write to a txt file you need to do this:

```
with open('you_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(onlyfiles)
```

If you already have a file created then use `'a'` instead of `'w'` otherwise it will overwrite the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from typing import List

onlyfiles: List[str] = [f for f in listdir('C:\\') if isfile(join('C:\\',f ))]
print(onlyfiles)

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    for file in onlyfiles:
        f.write(f"{file}\n")
```